# Why is my margin of error graph so spikey tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

So whenever I run my TensorFlow model the margin of error (loss / val_loss) graph is extremely back and fourth and I was wondering how I could stop this /reduce it here is a picture
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzNBS.png)

here's the code if anyone wants to run it should work fine as long as you have the pips

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import tensorboard

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

train_df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/ednsabkdzs8motw/ROK%20INPUT%20DATA%20-%20Sheet1.csv?dl=1')
eval_df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/irnqwc1v67wmbfk/ROK%20EVAL%20DATA%20-%20Sheet1.csv?dl=1')


train_df['Troops'] = train_df['Troops'].astype(float)
train_df['Enemy Troops'] = train_df['Enemy Troops'].astype(float)
train_df['Damage'] = train_df['Damage'].astype(float)
eval_df['Troops'] = eval_df['Troops'].astype(float)
eval_df['Enemy Troops'] = eval_df['Enemy Troops'].astype(float)
eval_df['Damage'] = eval_df['Damage'].astype(float)


damage = train_df.pop('Damage')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_df.values, damage.values))

test_labels = eval_df.pop('Damage')
test_features = eval_df.copy()


model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape = (8,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ]
)


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.summary()



history = model.fit(train_df, damage, validation_split=0.2, epochs=5000)

def plot_loss(history):
  plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='loss')
  plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='val_loss')
  plt.ylim([0, 2000])
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.ylabel('Error [MPG]')
  plt.legend()
  plt.grid(True)
plot_loss(history)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the idea/purpose of hidden layers with more units than input? Dimensionality reduction is often used to reduce the input and learn its representation.

Comment: I'm very new to machine learning so I based the values off of many of the tutorials I saw which used larger units than the input. If this is a bad practice I can definitely change it

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the labeled data has imbalanced values in your dataset which means you should use `mean_absolute_error` in place of `mean_squared_error` as a loss function to prevent outliers.

Please check below code:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.losses.MeanAbsoluteError())


history = model.fit(train_df, damage, 
                    validation_data=(test_features,test_labels), epochs=50)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/100
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 150ms/step - loss: 1015.9664 - val_loss: 129.8347
Epoch 2/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 244.7547 - val_loss: 28.9964
Epoch 3/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 629.1597 - val_loss: 20.9922
Epoch 4/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 612.6526 - val_loss: 45.7117
Epoch 5/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 335.1754 - val_loss: 93.0301
Epoch 6/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 168.1687 - val_loss: 128.6208
Epoch 7/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 406.5712 - val_loss: 129.7909
Epoch 8/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 391.4481 - val_loss: 113.0307
Epoch 9/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 182.2033 - val_loss: 83.6522
Epoch 10/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 176.4511 - val_loss: 68.1947
Epoch 11/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 266.6671 - val_loss: 71.0774
Epoch 12/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 40ms/step - loss: 198.2684 - val_loss: 88.3499
Epoch 13/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 119.8650 - val_loss: 100.7030
Epoch 14/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 189.6049 - val_loss: 94.6102
Epoch 15/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 146.5237 - val_loss: 77.1270
Epoch 16/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 106.8908 - val_loss: 60.1246
Epoch 17/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 132.0525 - val_loss: 56.3836
Epoch 18/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 129.6660 - val_loss: 64.7796
Epoch 19/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 118.3896 - val_loss: 68.5954
Epoch 20/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 114.2150 - val_loss: 67.0202
Epoch 21/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 112.6538 - val_loss: 65.2389
Epoch 22/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 107.1644 - val_loss: 59.4646
Epoch 23/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 106.9518 - val_loss: 51.4506
Epoch 24/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 107.4203 - val_loss: 48.4060
Epoch 25/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 108.1180 - val_loss: 48.5364
Epoch 26/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 106.6088 - val_loss: 47.0263
Epoch 27/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 107.6407 - val_loss: 47.3658
Epoch 28/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 105.1175 - val_loss: 45.2668
Epoch 29/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 105.9028 - val_loss: 45.2371
Epoch 30/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 103.5908 - val_loss: 48.8512
Epoch 31/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 102.6504 - val_loss: 53.9927
Epoch 32/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 100.8014 - val_loss: 58.1143
Epoch 33/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 114.6031 - val_loss: 49.8311
Epoch 34/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 104.9576 - val_loss: 45.7614
Epoch 35/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 102.5296 - val_loss: 44.3673
Epoch 36/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 105.3818 - val_loss: 40.8473
Epoch 37/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step - loss: 102.0235 - val_loss: 38.7967
Epoch 38/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 103.9142 - val_loss: 36.8466
Epoch 39/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 105.1095 - val_loss: 40.7968
Epoch 40/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 102.7449 - val_loss: 46.4677
Epoch 41/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 101.3321 - val_loss: 53.2947
Epoch 42/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 106.1829 - val_loss: 53.4320
Epoch 43/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 97.9348 - val_loss: 47.5536
Epoch 44/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 98.5830 - val_loss: 41.6827
Epoch 45/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 98.8272 - val_loss: 36.0022
Epoch 46/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 109.2409 - val_loss: 32.8524
Epoch 47/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step - loss: 112.1813 - val_loss: 38.2731
Epoch 48/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 99.5903 - val_loss: 40.8585
Epoch 49/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 106.2939 - val_loss: 47.6244
Epoch 50/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 97.1548 - val_loss: 51.4656
Epoch 51/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 97.9445 - val_loss: 46.3714
Epoch 52/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 96.2311 - val_loss: 39.1717
Epoch 53/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step - loss: 96.8036 - val_loss: 34.6192
Epoch 54/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 99.1502 - val_loss: 31.0388
Epoch 55/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 105.3854 - val_loss: 30.7220
Epoch 56/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 46ms/step - loss: 103.1274 - val_loss: 35.8683
Epoch 57/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step - loss: 94.2024 - val_loss: 38.4891
Epoch 58/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 95.7762 - val_loss: 41.9727
Epoch 59/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 93.3703 - val_loss: 30.4720
Epoch 60/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 93.3310 - val_loss: 20.7104
Epoch 61/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 98.0708 - val_loss: 12.8391
Epoch 62/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 101.6647 - val_loss: 24.7238
Epoch 63/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 89.2492 - val_loss: 35.5170
Epoch 64/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 114.9297 - val_loss: 19.0492
Epoch 65/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 89.8944 - val_loss: 9.8713
Epoch 66/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 119.7986 - val_loss: 12.5584
Epoch 67/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 85.2151 - val_loss: 23.7810
Epoch 68/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 91.6945 - val_loss: 27.0833
Epoch 69/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 91.0443 - val_loss: 20.8228
Epoch 70/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 88.2557 - val_loss: 17.0245
Epoch 71/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 89.2440 - val_loss: 14.7132
Epoch 72/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 89.3514 - val_loss: 13.7965
Epoch 73/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 87.8547 - val_loss: 12.9283
Epoch 74/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 87.2561 - val_loss: 13.1212
Epoch 75/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 87.3379 - val_loss: 15.1878
Epoch 76/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 85.2761 - val_loss: 16.0503
Epoch 77/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 87.9641 - val_loss: 17.0547
Epoch 78/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 82.7034 - val_loss: 15.5357
Epoch 79/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step - loss: 82.3891 - val_loss: 14.0231
Epoch 80/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 81.3045 - val_loss: 15.4905
Epoch 81/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 81.0241 - val_loss: 15.6177
Epoch 82/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 80.9134 - val_loss: 15.9989
Epoch 83/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 82.4333 - val_loss: 14.1885
Epoch 84/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 79.1791 - val_loss: 14.6505
Epoch 85/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 79.3381 - val_loss: 12.7476
Epoch 86/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 78.1342 - val_loss: 9.6814
Epoch 87/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 83.7268 - val_loss: 7.7703
Epoch 88/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 78.5488 - val_loss: 11.2915
Epoch 89/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 77.6771 - val_loss: 14.2054
Epoch 90/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 78.5004 - val_loss: 14.1587
Epoch 91/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 81.0928 - val_loss: 8.8034
Epoch 92/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 80.1722 - val_loss: 7.1039
Epoch 93/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 77.2722 - val_loss: 6.9086
Epoch 94/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step - loss: 77.4540 - val_loss: 11.6563
Epoch 95/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 84.5494 - val_loss: 6.5362
Epoch 96/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 76.0600 - val_loss: 15.5146
Epoch 97/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 91.8825 - val_loss: 5.5035
Epoch 98/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 83.6633 - val_loss: 10.4812
Epoch 99/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 76.4038 - val_loss: 11.0298
Epoch 100/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step - loss: 77.8150 - val_loss: 16.8254
```

and the loss graph looks like this:
[image]